# Interpreting the Higher-order Hodge-Laplace Operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, laplacian, derham-cohomology

As an operator on functions, one intuitive way to think about the Laplacian seems to be as an operator that returns the average difference between a function's value at a point and the values of its neighbouring points.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian-operator) explains how the Laplacian $\Delta f(\mathbf{0})$ at $\mathbf{0}$ of a function $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is limit of the (scaled) average difference
$$ \Delta f(\mathbf{0}) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \dfrac{2nr}{r^2} \dfrac{1}{\omega(S_r)} \int_{S_r} (f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{0}) ) d\omega(\mathbf{x}) $$
in a sphere around $\mathbf{0}$.

Suppose now we have a Riemannian manifold $M$, and we construct the De Rham complex
$$ \Omega^0(M) \xrightarrow{d^0} \Omega^1(M) \xrightarrow{d^1} \Omega^2(M) \xrightarrow{d^2} \ldots $$
where $d$ is the exterior derivative. The Riemannian structure allows us to define an adjoint to the exterior derivative and the Laplace-Hodge operator
$$ \Delta_n = (d^n)^\dagger d^n + d^{n-1} (d^{n-1})^\dagger $$
for any $n \geq 0$.

**My Question:** For $n > 0$, is there a way to think of $\Delta_n$ as comparing local averages of *$n$-forms*, similar to the way that $\Delta_0$ does for smooth functions?

In particular, any ideas on whether this works when $n =1$ would be much appreciated!